# Why does the sum of params in my model different from the correct one?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, mnist, generative-adversarial-network

Here is the requirement:

> Generator (5 points)
>
> For the generator, we will copy the architecture exactly from the
> InfoGAN paper. See Appendix C.1 MNIST. See the documentation for
> nn.ConvTranspose2d. We are always "training" in GAN mode.
>
> - Fully connected with output size 1024
> - ReLU
> - BatchNorm
> - Fully connected with output size 7 x 7 x 128
> - ReLU
> - BatchNorm
> - Reshape into Image Tensor of shape 7 x 7 x 128
> - Conv2D^T (Transpose): 64 filters of 4x4, stride 2, 'same' padding (use padding=1)
> - ReLU
> - BatchNorm
> - Conv2D^T (Transpose): 1 filter of 4x4, stride 2, 'same' padding (use padding=1)
> - TanH
> - Should have a 28 x 28 x 1 image, reshape back into 784 vector

Here is my code:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(noise_dim, 1024),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
        nn.Linear(1024, 7 * 7 * 128),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.BatchNorm1d(7 * 7 * 128),
        nn.Unflatten(1, (128, 7, 7)),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=1, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Flatten()
    )
```

This is something wrong with this code, cause when using the function to calculate the params in this model, my result (6,580,801) is different from the correct result (6,675,009):

```
def count_params(model):
    """Count the number of parameters in the model"""
    param_count = sum([p.numel() for p in model.parameters()])
    return param_count
```

My result is smaller than the correct one by 94,208 (1,024 * 4 * 23). Maybe I miss some layers. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for reading. The problem has been solved, cause we received a wrong test case from instructor.